# Angular_returns timespan as array

Tags: c#, angularjs, server-response

How to filter TimeSpan response with Angular.

This is what i get from server (JSON form of TimeSpan)

{"0":"\"","1":"0","2":"2","3":":","4":"0","5":"0","6":":","7":"0","8":"0","9":"\""}

The server call is

```
public TimeSpan GetCurrentWorkhourState(int employeeId, DateTimeOffset date)
```

Why does it send like json??

Comment: It would really help if you'd give some more context here. In particular, that looks like it should really just be a string response... please show your C# code.

Comment: On server side i am doing some calculations with time, and on client side i just need to show it. My server response is timespan, and this is what i get on client side, so i don't understand how to format this

Comment: Rather than describe it, please show the code on the C# side - it doesn't even need to be your *actual* code, so long as it's code which would give the same result (which you should check) - a method that always returns the same TimeSpan would be fine.

Comment: Not allowed to show code, but in Debug.Write (result), it shows 02:00:00

Comment: I'm sure you *are* allowed to show sample code that shows what your method declaration looks like - again, I'm not asking you to post the actual code, but *representative* code. If you can't even post the method declaration and describe what you're using (Web API?) then we're unlikely to be able to help you.

Comment: public TimeSpan GetCurrentWorkhourState(int employeeId, DateTimeOffset date), is that what you mean?
no use in showing code cause it just calls lot of other methods.

Comment: Yes, that's the one I mean - but put it in the question, with any attributes applied to it, along with details of what frameworks you're using. Currently you've given us *way* too little context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was using $resource which works only with objects and arrays, and not with raw strings